# Every combination of characters from dynamic list

Tags: java, string, combinatorics

I am stuck with a logic. I have a free text dropdown where users are free to enter up to 5 characters. Now every character has unicode accent characters associated to it. I generate unicode characters for the list associated for the characters. Now I want to generate all possible combinations with the characters from the list. I am a bit stuck since the list is generated dynamically. How do I possibly get to know which list should be iterated first? Below is my code.

```
//example String key="za";
if (key!=null) {
    List<Character> characList = key.chars()
                                    .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());//[z, a]
    List<List<String>> mainList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    for (Character characterObj:characList) {
        List<String> subList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Collection<String> charColl = unicodeMap.getCollection(characterObj.toString());
        subList = new ArrayList(charColl);//first iteration we get [ż, ź, ž] second iteration we get [à, á, â, ã, ä, å, ą, ă, ā]
        mainList.add(subList);//[[ż, ź, ž], [à, á, â, ã, ä, å, ą, ă, ā]]
    }
}
```

Now i want to generate combination of `String` from `[[ż, ź, ž], [à, á, â, ã, ä, å, ą, ă, ā]]`.
The `String` could have been azstu,etc. How do i iterate so that it will take care of all combinations from the associations of entered `String`. Please advise.

Desired output from the example String:-

```
żà
żá
żâ
żã
żä
żå
żą
żă
żā
.
.
.
```

Comment: Can you add your expected output for your example ?

Comment: The title says combinations but then you say permutations, what do you need exactly?

Comment: I have edited my question.. thanks for the correction @marc

Comment: desired output also added

Comment: In your case its not really a cross product because essentially if the user enters "xyz" then you have to generate all possible strings with all possible unicode variations of the xyz characters. I would probably maintain a mapping between character and variant list first. Then, I would iterate through the input string, get the variant list from the map, loop over the characters, and for each element recurse on the remaining string.

Comment: @JeremyFisher - i am maintaining a map for all associated unicode characters for a specific character. But once i fetch them i need to generate combination of those characters. for eg for x i might have 5 associations for y i might have 3 associations for z i might have 4 associations. All associations are in a list which i put them in a main list. Now i need to print combinations from those characters which are in those list which is a problem

Comment: I see. I guess it is technically a cross product sure, but What you need is all combinations of length N for a string of input length N, only using the unicode chars.So for xyz, if variations[x] = ["a"]. variations[y] = ["b", "c"], and variations[z] = ["d"], then the strings you need are ["abd", "abc"]. Im saying that instead of deciding to iterate over these lists, you will probably need to do this recursively

Comment: Basically, maintain a dynamic list of length N where N is input string length. Then as I described in my previous comment, iterate over input string. For each character, get corresponding variations. Loop over the variation list for that character, and choose one of the elements. Place it in your "result" list, then recurse on the remaining input string

Comment: Just to clarify, this is pretty much what @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks answer is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way can be recursively generate the string. Traverse the character's collection list by index and looping for every sublist.

```
List<String> genr(List<List<String>> list, int index, String now) {
    if (index >= list.size()) {
      return Arrays.asList(now);
    }
    List<String> subList = list.get(index);
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String value : subList) {
      res.addAll(genr(list, index + 1, now + value));
    }
    return res;
  }
```

And call like

```
List<List<String>> mainList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
mainList.add(Arrays.asList("ż", "ź", "ž"));
mainList.add(Arrays.asList("à", "á", "â", "ã", "ä", "å", "ą", "ă", "ā"));
List<String> data = genr(mainList, 0, "");
```

Output:
`[żà, żá, żâ, żã, żä, żå, żą, żă, żā, źà, źá, źâ, źã, źä, źå, źą, źă, źā, žà, žá, žâ, žã, žä, žå, žą, žă, žā]`

Demo [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HyOo785zD)

Comment: Downvoter should specify the reason for downvoting :|
@User - Can you please let me know for the combination za i have the associations as [[ż, ź, ž], [à, á, â, ã, ä, å, ą, ă, ā]] how will the above code generate combinations ?. Can you please help with an example.

Comment: @sTg Yes, it will generate all combinations. By example did you mean example output ?

Comment: Yeah if you can help me with input and output String as za with its associations  [[ż, ź, ž], [à, á, â, ã, ä, å, ą, ă, ā]]

Comment: @sTg I added a demo you can test

Comment: Can't understand the downvote to this question. Seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @raven1981 I totally don't understand what's going on downvoter's mind :(